# Не получается правильно распарсить ответ при помощи gson

Tags: java, android, json, android-vksdk, gson

Выдает npe на предпоследней строке:

```
VKRequest vkRequest = new VKApiGroups()
            .get(VKParameters
                    .from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, VKAccessToken.currentToken().userId,
                            VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1,
                            VKApiConst.FIELDS, "activity"));
    vkRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .create();
            GroupResponse groupResponse = gson
                    .fromJson(response.responseString, GroupResponse.class);
            List<Group> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.addAll(groupResponse.response.groups);
            post(items);
        }
    });
```

Вот pojo классы:

```
public class Group {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("activity")
    private String subName;
    @SerializedName("photo_50")
    private String photoURL;
}

public class GroupResponse {
    public Response response;

    public class Response {
        public int count;
        public List<Group> groups;
    }
}
```

Сам ответ приходит в правильном виде, в таком же как и указано в классах. Вот тут можно в этом убедиться https://vk.com/dev/groups.get

Comment: Вот тут ошибка? `post(items);` если да - то этого метода в вопросе нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы просто неправильно указали имя поля. В доке это `items`, а у вас `groups`